# What is the Teutonic/Saxon word that Huxley refers to?

Tags: etymology

Aldous Huxley on p.36 of "The Perennial Philosophy" writes:

“The word “personality” is derived from the Latin, and its upper partials are in the highest degree respectable.  For some odd philological reason, the Saxon equivalent of  “personality” is hardly ever used.  Which is a pity. For if it were used – used as currently as “belch” is used for “eructation” – would people make such a reverential fuss about the thing connoted as certain English-speaking philosophers, moralists and theologians have recently done? “

```
    ...
```

“But surely people would think twice about making or accepting this affirmation if, instead of “personality”, the word employed had been its Teutonic synonym, “selfness.”  “

I've not gotten further than to suspect that Selbst might be involved.
So what is this Teutonic / Saxon word that is "hardly ever used"?

Thanks much.

Comment: Are you asking for a word other than “selfless”, which you’ve quoted?

Comment: @Lawrence  Yes.  I think Huxley is referring to a Teutonic/Saxon word -- "the Saxon equivalent of personality" which is etymologically close to the English "selfness."

Comment: If it's not _an English word_ (ie, clearly _a loanword_), the question is off-topic on ELU. But Huxley is here obviously referring to 'the Saxon-**derived** equivalent of “personality” ', 'selfness'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Selfhood* is close to personality and both *self-* and *-hood* have Teutonic/Saxon origins.

Etymology Online:

> self-

> word forming element indicating "oneself," also "automatic," from Old English use of self (pron.) in compounds, such as selfbana "suicide," selflice "self-love, pride, vanity, egotism," selfwill "free will."

> self (pron.)

> Old English self, seolf, sylf "one's own person, -self; own, same," from Proto-Germanic *selbaz (source also of Old Norse sjalfr, Old Frisian self, Dutch zelf, Old High German selb, German selb, selbst, Gothic silba), Proto-Germanic *selbaz "self," from PIE *sel-bho-, suffixed form of root *s(w)e-, pronoun of the third person and reflexive (referring back to the subject of a sentence), also used in forms denoting the speaker's social group, "(we our-)selves" (see idiom).

> -hood

> word-forming element meaning "state or condition of being," from Old English -had "condition, quality, position" (as in cildhad "childhood," preosthad "priesthood," werhad "manhood"), cognate with German -heit/-keit, Dutch -heid, Old Frisian and Old Saxon -hed, all from Proto-Germanic *haidus "manner, quality," literally "bright appearance," from PIE (s)kai- (1) "bright, shining" (Cognates: Sanskrit ketu "brightness, appearance"). Originally a free-standing word (see hade); in Modern English it survives only in this suffix.

American Heritage Dictionary:

> selfhood
>
> n.
>
> 1. The state of having a distinct identity; individuality.

> 2. The fully developed self; an achieved personality.
> 3. Self-centeredness: "the cult of selfhood that became fashionable in the 1960s" (David Rankin)

This would likely be the word he was referring to.